# Does GCM count against bandwidth quota on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to figure out if implementing a GCM (global cloud messaging) syncing scheme will help defray the costs of outgoing bandwidth on Google's App Engine.

I know GCM is "free" i.e. there is no per message fee, but does it count against our outgoing bandwidth nonetheless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to use Url Fetch API to send requests to GCM servers, it will count toward your outgoing bandwidth, which you have 1GB per day free. Given average GCM message sizes  (and max of 4kb/message) you are more likelly to hit [Url Fetch qouta limits.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch)